# Can you still use Uber's developer APIs?

Tags: uber-api

Are Uber's API's still accessible? I have seen endless posts all over the internet about people trying to access them, but never any answers. I am able to authorize however I am limited by scopes. I am unable to request limited access to scopes through the uber developer dashboard as that section is completely blank for me. I am also unable to add scopes through the authorize API shown below as it just returns `invalid_scope`

`https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id=<Client ID>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost&scope=request`

I am just curious, are these even still available? If so, how were you able to add scopes to your account. All I want to do is estimate the price of a ride from one location to another.